# Elemntary OS - Login problem

Tags: linux, login, elementary-os

So I bought new laptop yesterday (Asus VivoBook X512DA) and I installed Elementary OS (5.1 Hera) on It.
Everything worked fine and installation process went normal, but the shut down process took really long (few minutes). After the shutdown I tried to turn on the laptop once again and after the login and successful signing in the screen just went black and I could see my mouse cursor (I could move it).
After that I had to turn it off manually, because everything was frozen and nothing showed up on the screen.
This problem kept on happening every now and then and right now I have no idea what to do. I don't know if it's laptop related problem or is it up to distribution that I'm using. There is no error code that I could trace ..
Can anyone help me please to trace down the problem?